# Should I bind to Properties of my control, or should I update them in OnPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Let's say I have `ControlA`, where in code-behind I have some property `PropertyA`, that are instance properties for bindable properties. I want to channel their values to `PropertyB` in control `ControlB` that is declared in XAML.

Now I can bind to property like so:

```
<ContentView
  ...
  x:Name="Self">

  <ContentView.Content>
    <ControlB
      x:Name="ConB"
      PropertyB="{Binding Source={x:Reference Self}, Path=PropertyA}/>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Or in the code behind like so:

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
{
  if(propertyName == nameof(PropertyA)
  {
    ConB.PropertyB = PropertyA;
  }
}
```

Is one of the approaches better than the other?

Comment: Well, when you bind them in XAML the binding code is autogenerated behind the scenes. What would be the benefit of writing it nanually?

Comment: Looking at the code samples and tutorials on the internet - I would say a lot, as a lot of people tell other to write it by hand. I was wondering if there is some point to it.

Comment: BTW I **always** have a (view-)model class for the control and so I bind to that in XAML - in your sample I do not see any model class

Comment: (FWIW @SirRufo - I used to always have a ViewModel. But sometimes that adds complexity/coding, without enough benefit. Recently I've been experimenting with putting that code in a second `partial class` file. So its part of code behind, but separated physically by being in another file.)

Comment: I prefer the first case. REASON: Put code where it applies, not in a centralized place requiring `if ... elseif ... `. That gets messy. And if you are looking at `ControlB`, you won't realize you also need to go look in `OnPropertyChanged` method, to understand what affects it. The only time I would consider it, is if it was an expression that was difficult to write in XAML. For example, if it depended on some other condition. `if (someSpecialFlag && ... nameof(PropertyA))`.

Comment: @toolmakerSteve thanks, I also think that having changes of the values scattered all over the code is worse than having it all nicely laid out in XAML. You can make it an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the first case.

REASON: Put code where it applies, not in a centralized place requiring

```
if ... elseif ...
```

That gets messy.

And if you are looking at `XAML` for `ControlB`, there is no indication that you also need to go look in `cs` file, `OnPropertyChanged` method, to understand what affects it.

---

The only time I would consider it, is if it was an expression that was difficult to write in `XAML`. For example, if it depended on some other condition:

```
if (someSpecialFlag && ... nameof(PropertyA)) ...
```

In such a case, I would put a prominent comment at the top of the cs code-behind file, alerting anyone who has to maintain the code that something special was done in `OnPropertyChanged`.

---

Its also worth looking into `Triggers`, as a way to represent conditions in `XAML`.